# centering divs with images for my top naviation

Tags: html, css

i am having trouble writing code for my top-nav

http://jsbin.com/evIhAkir/5/edit?html,css,output

i am trying to make social icons on my website horizontal in my nav bar but got stuck.
which is the best way to horizontal those icons.

Comment: Adding float: left to the divs tw-like and fb-like

Comment: not working the way you recommended

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/evIhAkir/6 i had been fixed your issue but please first improve your knowledge in html specially

- difference between width in % and px
- margin and padding
- float:left and right and clear both..
- hope you got the answer